# Select students not having any corresponding course

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple problem but I want to use Not having. I have two tables: student_table, and student_course

```
STUDENT (
    ID,
    Name
)

STUDENT_COURSE (
    ID,
    student_ID,
    course_ID
)
```

I want to select those student name that does not have any corresponding course_ID in the STUDENT_COURSE table, so I write

```
SELECT *
FROM STUDENT
LEFT JOIN STUDENT_COURSE ON STUDENT_COURSE.STUDENT_ID = STUDENT.ID
```

but how can I write Not having in the next?

Answer (score 4):

To find `STUDENT` with no `STUDENT_COURSE`, you could use different methods. See this [**article**](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) for the comparisons:

---

using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM STUDENT s
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM STUDENT_COURSE c WHERE c.STUDENT_ID = s.ID
)
```

using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT
    s.*
FROM STUDENT s
LEFT JOIN STUDENT_COURSE c
    ON c.STUDENT_ID = s.ID
WHERE c.ID IS NULL
```

using `NOT IN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM STUDENT
WHERE ID NOT IN(
    SELECT STUDENT_ID FROM STUDENT_COURSE
)
```

Comment: Doesn't left join produce the most efficient SQL/execution plan?

Comment: They're probably all the same.

Comment: Actually, the `left join` is the least efficient according to the article I referenced.

Comment: You could add and `EXCEPT` version to cover all the bases. I've noticed this question comes up a _lot_ on SO.

Comment: @shawnt00, `EXCEPT` is another alternative. Although, you have to extend the query to include columns you're not comparing.

Answer (score 4):

Just Add `[STUDENT_COURSE].[STUDENT_ID] IS NULL` filter which will find the students not invloved in any course

`Left Outer join` will produce `NULL` values for the right table columns which don't have a match.

```
SELECT *
FROM   [STUDENT]
       LEFT JOIN [STUDENT_COURSE]
              ON [STUDENT_COURSE].[STUDENT_ID] = STUDENT.ID
WHERE  [STUDENT_COURSE].[STUDENT_ID] IS NULL
```